# Not keep silent or to make silent in Job 41:12?

Tags: hebrew, textual-criticism, grammar, job

Job 41:4 (MT; v. 12 in English versions):

> NRSV: I will not keep silence concerning its limbs ...
>   ESV: I will not keep silence concerning his limbs ...
>   NASB: I will not keep silence concerning his limbs ...
>   YLT: I do not keep silent concerning his parts ...
>   BHS: כ= לֹא} {ק= לֹו}־אַחֲרִישׁ בַּדָּיו וּדְבַר־גְּבוּרֹות וְחִין עֶרְכֹּו׃}

The difference rests on whether to prefer the *ketib* לא (=not), negating the verb **[חָרַשׁ](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?t=kjv&strongs=h2790)** (=keep silent; "I will not keep silent concerning his boastings," or, the more literal and more plain: "I will not silence his boastings"); or the *qere* (here bracketed) לו (=to/for him; "For him I will silence his boastings").

**NOTE:** There are no less than [forty (40) translations of this verse into English](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Job41:12) that appear to **ignore** the suggested Masoretic reading for the *qere* (here bracketed) לו (=to/for). In other words, many, if not all, of the most popular and most widely-read English translations of this passage appear to prefer the *ketib* לא (=not). One sole exception appears to be the [International Children's Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2041%3A12&version=ICB;WLC) (?)!

Also, [LXX Job](http://katapi.org.uk/katapiNSBunix/Lxx/LxxHBByBC.php?B=18&C=41&Cv=1&version=Lxx) is characteristically "free" and is not obviously helpful here.

Question: Should we prefer the *ketiv*, which appears **universal** among the most popular and most widely-read English translations of the Bible? Or should we prefer the *qere*, which is the suggested Masoretic reading of this verse based on Jewish oral tradition?

---

Comment: A footnote to this verse in the _Oxford Jewish Study Bible_ says _Meaning of Heb. uncertain._

Answer (score 1):

Job is tough to translate. According to the anchor yale bible Job, it should be translated as:

> ```
>   Did I not silence his boasting, 
>   By the powerful word Hayyin prepared?
> ```

With the following commentary:

> KJ’s “**I will not conceal his parts, nor his power, nor his comely
> proportion**” is accepted in essence by most moderns. Moffatt’s bold
> venture, “No hunter would survive to boast and brag of his exploits
> and his fine arms,” is not hampered by rigid adherence to the text.
> JPS’s “**Would I keep silence concerning his boastings, / Or his proud
> talk, or his fair array of words?**” is the most exact rendering of the
> text. The word baddāyw here does not mean “his parts, members,” as in
> 18:13, but “his boasting,” as in 11:3; cf. Isa 16:6, 44:25 and 58:13
> (conjecturally); Jer 48:30, 50:36. The use in Isa 44:25 shows clearly
> the association of the word with heathen incantations. In the Ugaritic
> texts the root is used both as a verb and as a noun with the meaning
> “sing,” “song.” The real impediment to understanding of the text is
> the word ḥyn in the second line which is regularly explained as an
> anomalous form of the noun ḥēn, “grace, favor.” The Masoretic
> vocalization of the word is passing strange. If the Masoretes had
> thought the word should be read ḥēn, why did they not so vocalize it?
> Tur-Sinai suggests that the word is to be related to the root hyn, as
> in Deut 1:41, “You made bold to go up,” and with Ar. hayyin, “light,
> lightheartedly contemptuous.” Tur-Sinai, it seems, came close to the
> truth. I suggest that the troublesome word ḥyn represents an
> accidental corruption of a name or epithet of the god Koshar who is
> sometimes called hyn in the Ugaritic myths. The vocalization of this
> name is uncertain, but Ugaritic orthographic practice favors hayyān or
> hayyīn. Scribal confusion of h and ḥ is not surprising since the two
> letters are sometimes difficult to distinguish. This versatile deity
> Koshar serves in the Ugaritic texts as artisan, enchanter, and general
> factotum.

Pope, M. H. (2008). Job: Introduction, translation, and notes (Vol. 15, p. 338). New Haven;  London: Yale University Press.